# Matching words at different positions with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a string pattern like described below.

```
What I have                    = What I need

FII JS REAL CI  ER 10 115,06   = FII JS REAL CI
IRBBRASIL RE ONNM 100 19,10    = IRBBRASIL RE ON
MAGAZ LUIZA ONNM 40 38,00      = MAGAZ LUIZA ON
IT NOW IBOV CI 3 103,14        = IT NOW IBOV CI
01/00 IT NOW IBOV CI 40 103,13 = IT NOW IBOV CI
ITAUSA PN  EDJ N1 1.600 12,14  = ITAUSA PN
FII JS REAL CI # 10 120,00     = FII JS REAL CI
MAGAZ LUIZA PNNM 40 38,00      = MAGAZ LUIZA PN
01/00 PETROLEO BRA PN 30 14,48 = PETROLEO BRA PN
01/00 PETROLEO BRA PN          = PETROLEO BRA PN
AMBEV S/A ON                   = AMBEV S/A ON
```

When I try

```
wordRegex = re.compile(r'(.*)((O|P)N|UNT|CI)')
word = wordRegex.search(cell_value).group(0).strip()
```

It works in almost every case, except the ones where I have number/dates at the beginning.
If I try something like `(?<=\/\d{2}\s)(.*)((O|P)N|UNT|CI)` it will (obviously) only work in such cases.

I need help to figure out a pattern that works every time.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're trying to do from a few examples. You should try to define your desired outcome more rigorously.

Comment: @NicholasHunter I thought so too initially but if you look at his regex, I think it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns what you've listed

```
([A-Z][A-Z \/]*(CI|ON|PN|UNT))
```

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ttcQW7/2).

NOTE: The initial `[A-Z]` is to prevent the group returned from starting with a space. If you are OK with using `trim()`, then you can remove it.

---

Update...
Added Portguese characters as requested.

```
([A-ZÀÁÂÃÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜ \/.]*(CI|ON|PN|UNT))
```

I got the Portuguese characters from [this list](https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/psu/portuguese/). I manually added each one in because it's not all the characters from 192-220. If you are OK with adding in the other characters, you can do another range.

Also note... I removed the initial [A-Z] because it's just messy at this point once you add in all the new characters so you'll have to `.trim()` the result to clean up any spaces at the start of the string.

Comment: Thank you, @JeffC . But what if we have non-english characters, like  'Ã', that is commonly used in portuguese? 

I mean, how can I get `ATACADÃO S.A ON` or `ATACADAO S.A ON`  from `ATACADÃO S.A ONNM 1.500 16,58`? 

I know that I could simply add "Ã" to the pattern you suggested, like `([A-Z][A-ZÃ \/]*(CI|ON|PN|UNT))`.  But is there anything that automatically takes into consideration characters like Ã, É, Ç, etc?

Comment: First thing to do... and probably the most important thing... is to add some examples to your question. We can't know what we need to take into consideration if it isn't mentioned in the question. Add some specific examples of anything you think might cause problems with the regex by adding at least one example of each and what you expect to be the result (just add it to your existing table).

Comment: Also, you can only accept one answer. I know you accepted The fourth bird's answer earlier... just wanted you to realize you have now accepted mine. You should accept whichever YOU think is the best answer... also upvote any answer that you found helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added in the Portuguese characters you requested. I also updated the regex101.com link and added the example you gave above.

Comment: Adding manually the new characters was my solution as well. I was wondering with there was anything better. I'm grateful for your updated solution, though.  . Regarding one of your comments, to be honest, it was very difficult to choose one answer as the best one. Because I learned a lot from the fourth bird's explanation. However, after a few tries, I realized that yours was just as efficient but simpler and easier to implement. That was the reason why I changed my choice, although I am not sure how rude or misinterpreted this change may seem.

Comment: @Allan It sounds like you did the right thing. We get new people on here all the time and sometimes they switch answers without really understanding what they are doing. It sounds like you do and you made an intentional choice. Either way is fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

You might also start the match with any character except for chars A-Za-z and use a capture group starting with an uppercase char A-Z ending the match with one of the alternatives.

```
^[^A-Za-z]*([A-Z/]+(?:\s+[A-Z/]+)*\s+(?:[OP]N|UNT|CI))
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^A-Za-z]*` Optionally match any char except a char A-Z a-z
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z/]+` Match 1+ times a char A-Z or /
  - `(?:\s+[A-Z/]+)*` Optionally repeat matching 1+ whitespace chars and a char A-Z or /
  - `\s+(?:[OP]N|UNT|CI)` Match 1+ whitespace chars and one of the alternatives
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6oiVWK/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5wmpVp).

For example

```
import re

strings = [
    "FII JS REAL CI  ER 10 115,06",
    "IRBBRASIL RE ONNM 100 19,10",
    "MAGAZ LUIZA ONNM 40 38,00",
    "IT NOW IBOV CI 3 103,14",
    "01/00 IT NOW IBOV CI 40 103,13",
    "ITAUSA PN  EDJ N1 1.600 12,14",
    "FII JS REAL CI # 10 120,00",
    "MAGAZ LUIZA PNNM 40 38,00",
    "01/00 PETROLEO BRA PN 30 14,48",
    "01/00 PETROLEO BRA PN",
    "AMBEV S/A ON"
]

pattern = r"^[^A-Za-z]*([A-Z/]+(?:\s+[A-Z/]+)*\s+(?:[OP]N|UNT|CI))"
for s in strings:
    m = re.match(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
FII JS REAL CI
IRBBRASIL RE ON
MAGAZ LUIZA ON
IT NOW IBOV CI
IT NOW IBOV CI
ITAUSA PN
FII JS REAL CI
MAGAZ LUIZA PN
PETROLEO BRA PN
PETROLEO BRA PN
AMBEV S/A ON
```